# How do I create CollapsingToolbarLayout inner ViewPager like in that image that can swipe view next image and detail

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am new in android.

How do I create below image type layout?

I have try to demo of `CollapsingToolbarLayout` but I have no idea to how swap will be change. I won't to create that type of layout in my android app

[image: scroll vertical and swipe horizontal change new image detail]

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:background="@drawable/photo"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffe5e5e5"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <include layout="@layout/card_layout" />

          <!--  <include layout="@layout/card_layout" />

            <include layout="@layout/card_layout" />-->

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I made some formatting improvements, but I don't understand what exactly you're asking. My guess is that you want the ToolBar to become `ActionBar` like when you scroll the list, something like Telegram. Right?

Comment: Also, you should write the name of the app, in case someone wants to check it.

Comment: hello https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ogqcorp.bgh i wil create my app like this but view image layout I have no idea

Comment: Check this [link](http://androhub.com/android-toolbar-animation-using-design-support-library/). In this tutorial replace the imageview with viewpager.

Comment: thanks suresh kumar but possible to remove recyclerview and replaced by  nestedscrollview

Comment: i wan't to swap all layout and change data any where horizontal swap